# Assigning a variable from another variable

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to assign a variable from another variable. My code looks like this

```
   <#macro ctglink c rhs x y z m e b>
    <#assign ctg>
        <#if ctgroutes["${y}..${x}-${m}"]??>ctgroutes['${y}..${x}-${m}']
        <#elseif ctgroutes["${x}..${y}-${m}"]??>ctgroutes['${x}..${y}-${m}']
        <#else>{}</#if>
    </#assign>
```

However, this `ctg` variable is evaluating to just `ctgroutes['227..257-TPPMD04X02']` its not actually evaluating the string itself.

I have tried `?eval`, and `?interpret` and a bunch of other very hacky things to get this to work, no go. Even the `{}` is a string

Basically, I need the assign function to work like the old PHP `eval()` function or something. I am trying to access values in a Map whose keys are derived from the state of the data, so I don't see any easy way to query my Map without evaluating keys.

Update:

- I forgot to include the `elseif` in there
- Either way, I tried `<#assign ctg = ctgroutes["${y}..${x}-${m}"]!ctgroutes["${x}..${y}-${m}"]>` but I get the following error:

Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> ctgroutes["${y}..${x}-${m}"]!ctgroutes["${x}..${y}-${m}"]  [in template "RouteCompare-WptTable.ftlh" at line 5, column 24]

I would like a `null` result to just return an empty map, however that doesn't seem possible:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> ctgroutes["${y}..${x}-${m}"]!ctgroutes["${x}..${y}-${m}"]  [in template "RouteCompare-WptTable.ftlh" at line 5, column 24]
```

**So basically, my goal is I need to assign a variable that can take 1 of 3 values:**

1. ctgroutes["${y}..${x}-${m}"] // Assuming it is not null
2. ctgroutes["${x}..${y}-${m}"] // Assuming it is not null
3. {} // An empty map

**What is the best way to do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well what you want to achieve, you can write it like this:

```
<#assign ctg = ctgroutes["${y}..${x}-${m}"]!ctgroutes["${x}..${y}-${m}"]!{}>
```

Also note that `<#assign target>...</#assign>` is for capturing the output printed between the two tags into the `target` variable (instead of actually printing it). So `target` will always store a string or markup value. Also things outside FreeMarker tags and `${}` are just static text, and won't be parsed. So, the naive but working approach is just using `#if`/`#elseif`/`#else` and have a separate `#assign ctg = ...` inside each of them, but you can make this much sorter with the `!` operator, as it was shown.

Comment: Thanks though I updated my question as the suggestion didn't work

Comment: I have updated it again... I guess you want `!{}` at the end, not `!"{}"`, i.e, you want a real empty map.